# Check the contents of a variable

Tags: powershell

After creating a session, I am invoking the following:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock $Function:ReaddRoutes -ArgumentList $Global:_DeviceNumberInfoIP.ServiceNetGW
```

The above runs the following function on the remote server:

```
function ReaddRoutes {
  if ($Global:datacentre -like '(PINK3)') {
    route delete 10.252.0.0
    route delete 10.191.192.0

    route add -p 10.252.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 $args[0]
    route add -p 10.191.192.0 mask 255.255.192.0 $args[0]
  }
}
```

Now the problem is, if I remove the `if` statement, the function will run. But I have quite a few data centers to compare and add routes accordingly. I've tried many variations of the `-like` operator.

The variable `$global:datacentre` contains something similar to 'Panther  (Pink3)'.

Could it be because I am calling this from a invoke-command and it is behaving differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

Since this function is being invoked on a remote server, I had to parse the datacenter variable.

After having a nice sleep and trying again, it does kinda make sense... So any functions that run on a remote server need to be in the -argument list.

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock $Function:ReaddRoutes -ArgumentList $Global:_DeviceNumberInfoIP.ServiceNetGW,$Global:datacentre
```

And for the function:

```
if ($args[1] -like '*(LON3)'){


        route delete 10.252.0.0
        route delete 10.191.192.0

        #Arg[0] is the Servicenet GW
        Route add -p 10.252.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0 $args[0]
        Route add -p 10.191.192.0 mask 255.255.192.0 $args[0]

       }
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 2):

`-like` is a wildcard match operator.  To find match for anything ending in (PINK3), use:

```
if ($Global:datacentre -like '*(PINK3)')
```

Without any wildcard characters in the match argument, you're essentially requiring an exact match.

```
if ($Global:datacentre -like '(PINK3)')
```

is functionally equivalent to

```
if ($Global:datacentre -eq '(PINK3)')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I figured out my problem.